# OutLook Task request in php

Tags: php, outlook

Im trying to create a project module in my site, in this project users can submit sugestions, bugs helping requests

My idea is, that each time a user submit a bug ou sugestion an email is sent to my email

The problem: I also want to set a task. Since in my private PC, I read the email in outlook, and it would be great to read an email and "acept" the task.

PS: the web server of is in Ubuntu so the server and pc are not the same

Answer (score 0):

In the mail, Include a link. The link when clicked must "accept" the task.

E.g:

Lets say in your mail:

> www.xyz.com/acceptTask.php?taskId=123

In your php script:

```
<?php

//check if an admin is logged in, if not redirect to login page

//if admin logged in, then accept the task in your php script according to business logic

?>
```